# Derive upper and lower bounds for T(n) = 3T(n/5) + T(n/2) + 2^n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

I have a recurrence where `T(n) = 3T(n/5) + T(n/2) + 2^n` and I want to find the upper and lower bounds for T(n).

But, I cannot use master method to solve the recurrence. I have just learned recurrence and it seems solving this is too hard. Can you please help me with this? How do I solve it if I can't use the master method?

Answer (score -1):

```
you cant solve this relation with akra-bazzi method because 2^n is not polynomial .
But for solving with finding bounds :

it's obvious that:

1)  T(n) >= 2^n (cause we can see in the relation we have 2^n and other things :)) ) 
and we know that the :

2) T(n) <= 4T(n/2) + 2^n . and we can solve this with master method and the answer of 4t(n/2) + 2^n is θ(2^n) .

1+2) now we have this : θ(2^n) <= T(n) <= 2^n . 

so we have the answer :
T(n) ∈  θ(2^n).
```